# Kitchen drain older copper metal steel replace put a new one in

Tags: kitchens, drain, replacement, old-work, rot

I'm trying to remove a drain out of a sink it's the older one I don't think it's ever been replaced the actual centerpiece it's letting all the debris go down it needs to be taken out so what do I do just bang on it there's no eenter link description herears there's no bolts there's just a thread at the bottom add rain and the thread

Comment: please format the string of words into proper sentences

Comment: Pictures would help a lot.

Comment: Strainer pluds can be bought in various sizes.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.